# Linux script cp changing file name

Tags: linux, bash, cp, bin, recycle

I'm trying to make a sort of recycling bin. I have a delete function which sends the selected file to the recycling bin and adds the location of the directory it was stored in to the file. The problem is when I obtain the location from the script using tail. Although the script works, it renames the file to tail. Could anyone explain why the cp is renaming the file? Here is a snippet from where I believe the problem is:

```
destination=(tail $1 -n 1)
cp ~/Recycling/$1 $destination 
rm ~/Recycling/$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a `$` before the parenthesis:

```
destination=$(tail $1 -n 1)
cp ~/Recycling/$1 $destination 
rm ~/Recycling/$1
sed -i '$d' $destination # this removes the last line from the file
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `$` before the parens:

```
destination=$(tail $1 -n 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want

```
$(tail $1 -n 1)
```

or

```
`tail $1 -n 1`
```